# How do you get all the tweets from this account by ID or classname with dart?

Tags: html, flutter, dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parsee;
...
                    try {
                      var doc = await http.get(Uri.parse(
                          'https://twitter.com/Test15598298'));
                      var parsed = parsee.parse(doc.body);
                      var element = parsed.getElementsByClassName(
                          'here is the classname/id');
                      //var
                      if (element == null) {
                        print('Null');
                      } else {
                        print(element);
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      rethrow;
                    }
```

I want to retrieve tweet from this example(lnglat of this tweet):
[image: here is the example]

I'm having trouble printing the content of my tweet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use twitter api for this.

1. A twitter developers account is needed :   Create one at [Twitter Developers console](https://developer.twitter.com/en)
2. To access the api you will need set of keys from the developers console. After that you can use search api to get the result you are
   looking for.
3. Optionally, you can use pub.dev package `dart_twitter_api` to speed up the process using the methods provided in the library.
   [Link to dart_twitter_api package](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_twitter_api)